# Security problem as using same apple id on my mother and my phone bcz of which all imsgs and calls are going to her also

Tags: macos

I have 2 iphones one is with my mother and one is with me but apple id on both the phones is same which is creating problm for me as my imessages and facetime calls are going to her also so how can i make my stuff secure and stop my calls and message on going on her iphone????

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
You can stop using the same Apple ID.

If you want to be able to share apps/books/music etc - but not personal data - then set up [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060)